# ChartJS v2 - Outer arc when hover on a pie/doughnut segment

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, chart.js, outer-join

I need to create a pie/doughnut chart using ChartJS v2 which shows the outer arc of a segment when user hover on it. Something similars like this:

[image: Outer Arc]

Does anyone know how can I achieve this?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You could achieve that by setting the **`hoverBorderWidth`** for *datasets*

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ["Microsoft Internet Explorer", "Google Chrome", "Mozilla Firefox", "Opera", "Safari"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Number of votes',
            data: [60, 20, 10, 8, 2],
            backgroundColor: ['#96ceff', '#424348', '#91ee7c', '#f7a35b', '#8286e9'],
            borderColor: '#fff',
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBorderColor: ['#96ceff', '#424348', '#91ee7c', '#f7a35b', '#8286e9'],
            hoverBorderWidth: 8
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
            displayColors: false
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="350" height="350"></canvas>
```

or, you could also create your own *plugin*.

Comment: Yes I saw that option too but it also increases the inner border which doesn't look like

Comment: @Flame113 Yes, I know but, unfortunately that's the only built-in option available in *ChartJS*  at-the-moment to visualize such border. Maybe, you need to create your own plugin to acquire the border you like :)